# Missing properties in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

```
class RolloutStoreClass {

import { observable, action, makeAutoObservable } from "mobx";


    public queue = observable<IDeploymentProject>([]);
    public inProcess = observable<IDeploymentProject>([]);
    public successfull = observable<IDeploymentProject>([]);
    public failed = observable<IDeploymentProject>([]);


constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }


@action
    private clearQueue(): void {
        this.queue = [] ;
        this.inProcess = [];
        this.failed = [];
        this.successfull = [];
    }
}

export const RolloutStore = new RolloutStoreClass();
```

I get the issue on the clearQueue Function exactlly on this. queue

Error is:

> In the "never []" type, the following properties of the "Observable Array " type are missing: "spliceWithArray, clear, replace, remove, toJSON".

Comment: Yes, queue is an `observable<IDeploymentProject>` and in the clearQueue function you assign it to a simple array.

I think there is a clear function on the observable type in mobx: https://mobx.js.org/api.html#observablearray

instead of reassign to a new array, you probably can do this.queue.clear()

Answer (score 0):

You either need to make your `queue` (and other fields) regular array, all observability will still work.

Or use `.clear()` method inside `clearQueue`:

```
    private clearQueue(): void {
        this.queue.clear();
        // ...
    }
```

One more thing: when you use `makeAutoObservable` you don't need to explicitly mark `action`'s `observable`'s and so on, you can just drop all the decorators:

```
class Foo {
    // Don't need explicit observable decorator
    public queue: IDeploymentProject[] = [];
    // ...

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }
    
    // You can remove action decorator
    private clearQueue(): void {
        this.queue = [] ;
        this.inProcess = [];
        this.failed = [];
        this.successfull = [];
    }
}
```